# bootstrap datatables table tools button shows wierd images

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I use a datatable to load data from a table in my page. The table is marked with the id="datatables" and i use the following code to initialise datatable on it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#datatables').dataTable( {
            "sDom": 'T<"clear"><"H"lf>rt<"F"ip>',
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
            }
        } );

    } );
```

I get a problem of loading garbage images while loading the page in chrome whereas it is fine in firefox. Everything works fine without the table tools in chrome. When i add the table tools, the buttons load some random and sometimes garbage images. I tried clearing the cache, but no hope. At certian times ie. once in a bluemoon, it does load cleanly and goes off the next reload. The images become ok when I right click on the page and open up inspect element somewhere.

The chrome console shows 200 OK for loading of the swf file. I tried loading the file seperately as:

```
"oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        }
```

still no hope. It works fine in firefox. Problem exists only in chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is problem of loading of flash images like swf in chrome which was an existing bug. It had been rectified by the chrome team in the new releases. Bootstrap datatables works fine in the new interface. Please try upgrading your chrome.